# GORM Mapping Manifesto :: To Long or not to Long

Tags: hibernate, testing, grails, grails-orm

Fairly basic problem but it's roots run deep in the framework (and there is little definitive information on the subject), so I am putting it out here so as to save others the pain (and to verify that I am correct or not in my thinking).

What is the problem?

Grails automatically injects an id field of type Long into your domains ([see Beckwith's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232794/getting-the-id-of-a-one-to-many-loaded-object-without-another-trip-to-the-db-with)). When using a legacy DB Grails maps Longs to bigints by default, an inefficient storage type that anyone dealing with large million+ record tables would avoid.

Upon discovering this a few months ago I set to work on getting a "proper" column type in place for my domain ids. Not having a Java background, blindly I thought, Long-bad, Integer-good and set hibernate mapping dialect for Integer types to what I would do by hand in mysql

> registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, 'mediumint unsigned')

and then defined "Integer id" in all of my domains (not necessary according to Bert's comment in link above). Everything worked swimmingly, wonderful, on to other things.

Fast forward to Grails 2.0 (as I could not resist all of the goodies ;-)) and Spock. For the life of me I could not figure out why, despite 2.0 new in-memory GORM and support for dynamic finders, that Domain.findByFoo(fooVal) would always return null (yes, I @Mock(Domain) and populate with test data). In fact, both within the test itself and @TestFor target, the only GORM methods that worked were save() and get(); everything else returned null.

I whipped up a quick test app, domain + controller + spoc spec and discovered the source of the problem: If you use a property type other than Long for your ids (including referenced FKs), your @Mock domain(s) will be rendered useless.

So, am I correct or not in saying that one must use Long ids in order to take full advantage of the framework? @Mock + @TestFor + Spock is an incredible combo!  Guidance appreciated before I head down refactor-to-Long road...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot imagine any realistic scenario where the difference between Integer and Long would make any noticeable difference to performance (which seems to have been the original motivation for making this change).

If using Long works, but Integer causes problems, then use Long and move onto more important tasks. I would only worry about this if you can *prove* that using Integer makes any significant difference.

### Update

You're right, I did completely miss the point about the database type that Grails automatically uses for Long. As you seem to already know, you can control the database type in the mapping closure of your domain class, e.g.

```
class Person {
   Long id

   static mapping = {
      // See here for alternatives to integer, and how they map to DB types
      // http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes
      id type:'integer'
   }
}
```

You also brought up in the comments

> dealing with Long at code level where one must specify def foo(Long id) {...} and params.id.toLong() as opposed to Integer

You can simply define an action as

```
def myAction = {Person p ->

}
```

or

```
def myAction = {
   Person p = new Person(params)
}
```

And Grails will take care of type-converting the id request parameter to `Person.id`, regardless of whether it's a Long, Integer, BigDecimal, etc.

Comment: Don thanks, think you missed the main point: the primary issue is about how Grails maps Long to bigint in legacy DBs, which is an highly inefficient PK storage type that manifests itself as a problem when dealing with large tables. At the code level I am not at all concerned about the performance of Long vs Integer, but I would like to avoid having to do things like params.id.toLong() or other conversion hoop jumping when Groovy defaults to Integer for numeric types. Correct if wrong, maybe it's all totally unfounded and grails automagically converts numeric types for us, but have my doubts...

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, mapping Long to mediumint instead of bigint at db level is easily solved, so the remaining unknown niggle is: dealing with Long at code level where one must specify def foo(Long id) {...} and params.id.toLong() as opposed to Integer, which is I assume everyone's code default. E.g. if you were to Type out [1,2,3].each{Integer i-> ...} and the like.  Basically, Long when it relates to persistence ids (including applicable methods sigs and params conversions).  Otherwise Integer or def as you like.

Comment: Don, yes, that is good to know re: automagically converting params. Defining an id column is extraneous, Grails injects a Long id for you, and in-memory GORM implementation will completely neuter your @Mock'd domains in 2.0 unless your ids are of type Long. So, moral of the story is, Long, Long, Long your ids (goes without saying that referenced FKs like fooID must be Long). The way to explicitly map property types to legacy DB storage types is via custom hibernate dialect, you can say that property type Longs (BIGINT) should be mapped to 'mediumint unsigned' and have sanity on both ends ;-)