# Getting the one-to-many foreign key value without another trip to the DB

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have 2 domain classes like this :

```
class A {
   B b
   static mapping = {
      table "table_a"
      b column: "primary_id", index: "b_id_idx"        
   }
}

class B {
   Long primaryId
}
```

When I retrieve an instance of A the ID of the corresponding instance of B is retrieved from the database. However, when I attempt to access that ID via something like:

```
A a = A.get(11)
Long bid = a.b.primaryId
```

the whole object is loaded from the database.

I tried the solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232794/getting-the-id-of-a-one-to-many-loaded-object-without-another-trip-to-the-db-wit) with this code:

```
A a = A.get(11)
Long bid = a.bPrimaryId
```

but the `a.bPrimaryId` returns null.

It seems that grails can't link the one-to-many primary key object with the foreign key attribute `bPrimaryId` if its name is different to "id".
I don't want rename "primary_id" by "id" to avoid impacts to other parts of the code.

Any idea?

Comment: have you tried `a.bId`?  or checked, what the actual name of the foreign key in A is in the db?

Comment: the a.bId instruction return null as well.

Comment: the a.bId instruction return null as well. The name of the foreign key is : "b_primary_id"

Comment: Ok, i misread this.  primaryId is just a field in b.  you can not access it by A directly.  you would only be able to get the actual primary key of a B this way (a.bId).  You would have to use a join/projection/...